# Can Facebook's fb:comments notify me when a new comment is posted?

Tags: facebook, fbml

I'm using fb:comments as described [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/comments_%28XFBML%29).

Comments work fine but I can't find a way to be notified when a new comment is added. Is there a way to easily find new comments (without visiting my 3000 articles each time)?

I know FB did some changes to the way notifications work but I hope they left a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should able to do this by using the event subscription:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe

Comment: It seems that this works only when the logged-in/connected user adds a comment - but it doesn't trigger when someone else adds a new comment to the comments-box, which is what I think the OP is looking for (and well, that's what *I'm* looking for anyway...)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way right now. Maybe one day they'll add it to the real-time updates: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime

I think for now you may be stuck polling for them with:

https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/comments

(for example)

https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552_118464504835613/comments?access_token=2227470867%7C2.FEEAvi5BbYBzdSQ5WM8otg__.3600.1288310400-100000309017680%7CeGASV-HXqF18-L0Y1x6_kVcjgxM

Comment: This isn't correct, you can use the FB.event.subscribe like mentioned by ry0ohki.